# Content-Security-Policy causing strange site rendering?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, nginx, headers

I'm trying to figure out why with the `Content-Security-Policy` header enabled in my nginx conf, some of the elements on my site seem a bit odd. Everything loads properly (status 200) but some images might be a bit smaller or some html rendering is a slightly off in the browser. It's bizarre; I can't really explain it. What's the proper usage of Content-Security-Policy? And why might it break sites where 100% of the sites content (no CDN) is originating from the root or /uploads?

```
user www-data;
worker_processes  auto;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    charset utf-8;
    server_tokens  off;

    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
    add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
    add_header Referrer-Policy "SAMEORIGIN" always;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
    add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self';";

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    gzip on;
    gzip_comp_level 2;
    gzip_min_length 1000;

    server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:80;
    server_name website.com;
    root /var/www/website/;
    index index.php index.html;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~* .(png|ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|css|html|txt|php)$ {
        expires 2d;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|POST)$) {
         return 444;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hard to tell without at least a screenshot. If I were to debug this, I would retrieve all the page elements with `wget` or `curl`, with and without the Content-Security-Policy, and compare the results. I would also try with different browsers...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Then compare the curl outputs? What differences in output would I be looking for exactly?

Comment: No idea. Diff is your friend... You may also discover that some elements are missing.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what your site's content is, it's hard to know why CSP is having an apparent effect on it. Perhaps you're using a build-tool that alters your site's image files, or maybe a framework that changes your site's appearance in subtle ways.

To be sure of whether or not Content Security Policy is to blame, you can enable reporting of violations by including:

```
Content-Security-Policy: ...; report-uri https://endpoint.com; report-to groupname
```

This is discussed in greater detail in the [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/report-uri). As mentioned in the article, be sure to include both **report-uri** and **report-to** for compatibility reasons. You could also use 
**Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only** which may be easier to implement and interpret. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only).

If you're using Chrome, you can double-check in your Dev tools console for errors related to CSP since Chrome has pretty generous error reporting for this. This can be done without making the above changes.